# Does Firebase persistence system can help to make less data download from realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

Is it good practice to use --

```
    query.keepSynced(true);
```

in Firebase recycler adapter? Will it help to make downloading of data less from the server?
Also how to disable persistence for a specific node though I am using --

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

In my Application class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keepSynced effectively just leaves a listener attached to a location all of the time.  If that's what you need, then use it.  If not, then don't.  It doesn't really have any other effect.

It's not really about good or bad practices, it's about making sure a location is always in sync with the server, if that's what you need.  If anything, it causes **more** data to be downloaded than normal.  The normal situation is adding a listener when the results of a query are being displayed, and removing that listener when that UI is gone.

You can't disable persistence for a specific node.  Persistence is either on or off entirely.

Comment: Question to Doug. Regarding setting persistence to false, after it has been set to true. I have not been able to make that work successfully, I presume because references have been used. Is it possible to turn it off (set it to false) after it has been switched on and references used, for example when logging out?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Please ask a new question that illustrates what exactly isn't working the way you expect with your code, and how you're observing it.

Comment: Will do. Will have title: 'Calling .setPersistenceEnabled(false) when logging out of app not working' . Thanks.